# Why Sinatra request takes EM thread?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, eventmachine

Sinatra app receives requests for long running tasks and EM.defer them, launching them in EM's internal pool of 20 threads. When there are more than 20 EM.defer running, they are stored in EM's threadqueue by EM.defer.

However, it seems Sinatra won't service any requests until there is an EM thread available to handle them. My question is, isn't Sinatra suppose to use the reactor of the main thread to service all requests? Why am I seeing an add on the threadqueue when I make a new request?

Steps to reproduce:

```
Access /track/
Launch 30 /sleep/ reqs to fill the threadqueue
Access /ping/ and notice the add in the threadqueue as well as the delay
```

Code to reproduce it:

```
require 'sinatra'
#monkeypatch EM so we can access threadpools
module EventMachine 
  def self.queuedDefers 
    @threadqueue==nil ? 0: @threadqueue.size 
  end
  def self.availThreads 
    @threadqueue==nil ? 0: @threadqueue.num_waiting
  end
  def self.busyThreads 
    @threadqueue==nil ? 0: @threadpool_size - @threadqueue.num_waiting
  end   
end 
get '/track/?' do
  EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do 
    p "Busy: " + EventMachine.busyThreads.to_s + "/" +EventMachine.threadpool_size.to_s + ", Available: " + EventMachine.availThreads.to_s + "/" +EventMachine.threadpool_size.to_s + ", Queued: " + EventMachine.queuedDefers.to_s 
  end 
end

get '/sleep/?' do
  EM.defer(Proc.new {sleep 20}, Proc.new {body "DONE"})
end

get '/ping/?' do
  body "pong"
end
```

I tried the same thing on Rack/Thin (no Sinatra) and works as it's supposed to, so I guess Sinatra is causing it.

```
Ruby version: 1.9.3.p125
EventMachine: 1.0.0.beta.4.1
Sinatra: 1.3.2
OS: Windows
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so it seems Sinatra starts Thin in threaded mode by default causing the above behavior. 
You can add

```
set :threaded, false
```

in your Sinatra configure section and this will prevent the Reactor defering requests on a separate thread, and blocking when under load.

[Source1](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1638)

[Source2](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/blob/master/lib/thin/connection.rb#L48-51)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something about your question, this is pretty much how EventMachine works. If you check out the [docs for EM.defer](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/eventmachine.rb#L972), they state:

> Don't write a deferred operation that will block forever. If so, the
>   current implementation will not detect the problem, and the thread
>   will never be returned to the pool. EventMachine limits the number of
>   threads in its pool, so if you do this enough times, your subsequent
>   deferred operations won't get a chance to run.

Basically, there's a finite number of threads, and if you use them up, any pending operations will block until a thread is available.

It might be possible to bump `threadpool_size` if you just need more threads, although ultimately that's not a long-term solution.

[Is Sinatra multi threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278817/is-sinatra-multi-threaded) is a really good question here on SO about Sinatra and threads. In short, Sinatra is awesome but if you need decent threading you might need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Muffinista, it is clear how EventMachine works. My question is more about why Sinatra (running on my main thread) can't service a simple request when the EM thread is full.
Sinatra shouldn't be affected by the EM queue since it's running on the main Thread and never blocks. Also nothing suggests that servicing a simple 
get "/"
  body "pong"
end
would EM.defer a new thread, however the code above shows a case where it does.

Comment: Your example doesn't actually run for me, so I can't test, but if I'm not mistaken, in your scenario, EM.defer will be run for all requests. Which makes sense -- Sinatra has no idea what your app is going to do or how long it will take.