# Does this block the event loop?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a `sinatra` app that is using `thin` as it's web server. I interact with my database via `ActiveRecord`.

If in an endpoint, I do this:

```
get '/test' do
  Model.create(.....)
end
```

Does the `Model.create(.....)` block the event loop (thin uses `eventmachine` internally)? If so, how bad is this and what are the alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: All actions "block" a thread until they complete. If the eventmachine thread (it only uses one) calls the request method then it will block until the method completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that `thin` is threaded by default, unless you disable that. So your request handler can be executed asynchronously using `Eventmachine::Defer`.

Yes, as the comment by @user2246674 says, if your handler is executed in the reactor thread then it will block everything.

As to the alternatives, I just searched Google for `ActiveRecord and Eventmachine` and the first hit was this post with some code: http://www.mikeperham.com/2010/03/30/using-activerecord-with-eventmachine/. You might find it useful to take a look at "em-synchrony": https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony that has support for `ActiveRecord`.

Here is also my own question on a related subject: [async requests using sinatra streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993386/async-requests-using-sinatra-streaming-api) There I use Sinatra's streaming API to implement asynchronous request processing.

I personally would use direct DB access from my Sinatra app. That is what I always do. `ActiveRecord` is too heavy for me.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. What do you mean y direct DB access? Do you mean use the mysql2 gem and pass in raw queries?

Comment: here is a post about `EM.Defer`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881594/why-sinatra-request-takes-em-thread?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does block. If you are on Mysql you can make requests using mysql2 gem, it supports async requests.
https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2