# Handle Sinatra and Faye in same EventMachine Performantly

Tags: ruby, sinatra, thin, eventmachine, faye

I am writing a web application that uses both [Sinatra](http://sinatrarb.com)—for general single-client synchronous gets—and [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby.html)—for multiple-client asynchronous server-based broadcasts.

My (limited) understanding of [EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) was that it would allow me to put both of these in a single process and get parallel requests handled for me. However, my testing shows that if either Sinatra or Faye takes a long time on a particular action (which may happen regularly with my real application) it blocks the other.

How can I rewrite the simple test application below so that if either `sleep` command is uncommented the Faye-pushes and the AJAX poll responses are not delayed?

```rb
%w[eventmachine thin sinatra faye json].each{ |lib| require lib }

def run!
  EM.run do
    Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')

    webapp = MyWebApp.new
    server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(mount:'/', timeout:25)

    dispatch = Rack::Builder.app do
      map('/'){     run webapp }
      map('/faye'){ run server }
    end

    Rack::Server.start({
      app:     dispatch,
      Host:    '0.0.0.0',
      Port:    8090,
      server:  'thin',
      signals: false,
    })
  end
end

class MyWebApp < Sinatra::Application
  # http://stackoverflow.com/q/10881594/405017
  configure{ set threaded:false }

  def initialize
    super
    @faye = Faye::Client.new("http://localhost:8090/faye")
    EM.add_periodic_timer(0.5) do
      # uncommenting the following line should not
      # prevent Sinatra from responding to "pull"
      # sleep 5
      @faye.publish( '/push', { faye:Time.now.to_f } )
    end
  end

  get ('/pull') do
    # uncommenting the following line should not
    # prevent Faye from sending "push" updates rapidly
    # sleep 5
    content_type :json
    { sinatra:Time.now.to_f }.to_json
  end

  get '/' do
    "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'><head>
      <meta charset='utf-8'>
      <title>PerfTest</title>
      <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js'></script>
      <script src='/faye/client.js'></script>
      <script>
      var faye = new Faye.Client('/faye', { retry:2, timeout:10 } );
      faye.subscribe('/push',console.log.bind(console));
      setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/pull',console.log.bind(console))
      }, 500 );
      </script>
    </head><body>
      Check the logs, yo.
    </body></html>"
  end
end

run!
```

Comment: Note that calling `sleep` is a bad way to test this - it will actually sleep the entire thread including your EventMachine reactor - remember EventMachine apps only run in a single thread.

Comment: @MartinKonecny How does `sleep` differ from, say, `999999.times{ Math.sqrt(rand) }` or  `exec("sleep 5")`? Those also block any single-thread, right? That's what I'm trying to simulate, a blocking command that takes a long time.

Answer (score 1):

> How does sleep differ from, say, 999999.times{ Math.sqrt(rand) } or exec("sleep 5")? Those also block any single-thread, right? That's what I'm trying to simulate, a blocking command that takes a long time.

Both cases would block your reactor/event queue. With the **reactor pattern**, you want to *avoid* any CPU intensive work, and focus purely on IO (i.e. network programming).

The reason why the single-threaded reactor pattern works so well with I/O is because IO is not CPU intensive - instead it just blocks your programs while the system kernel handles your I/O request.

The reactor pattern takes advantage of this by immediately switching your *single* thread to potentially work on something different (perhaps the response of some other request has completed) until the I/O operation is completed by the OS.

Once the OS has the result of your IO request, EventMachine finds the callback you had initially registered with your I/O request and passes it the response data.

So instead of something like

```
# block here for perhaps 50 ms
r = RestClient.get("http://www.google.ca") 
puts r.body
```

EventMachine is more like

```
# Absolutely no blocking
response = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new('http://google.ca/').get

# add to event queue for when kernel eventually delivers result
response.callback {
    puts http.response
}
```

In the first example, you would need the multi-threaded model for your web server, since a single thread making a network request can block for potentially seconds.

In the second example, you don't have blocking operations, so one thread works great (and is generally faster than a multi-thread app!)

If you ever do have a CPU intensive operation, EventMachine allows you to cheat a little bit, and start a new thread so that the reactor doesn't block. Read more about [EM.defer](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/wiki/EM::Deferrable-and-EM.defer) here.

One final note is that this is the reason Node.js is so popular. For Ruby we need EventMachine + compatible libraries for the reactor pattern (can't just use the blocking `RestClient` for example), but Node.js and all of it's libraries are written from the start for the reactor design pattern (they are callback based).