# sinatra service

Tags: ruby, sinatra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Sinatra multi threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278817/is-sinatra-multi-threaded)

I have a web service that requires running on Ruby 1.8.7. Currently I'm using Sinatra with Thin to host the service.

I did a test to submit two requests: "A" and "B". If I submit only A, which is just a "helloworld" request, I get the result back immediately. If I send request B first, which takes more time and resources than request A, I receive results for A and B about the same time. It seems like Sinatra handles them synchronously.

Is there a way to make Sinatra multithreaded?

Comment: I use daemon to run it as windows service. The script to run run is: myclass.run! :host => 'localhost', :port => 8000, :server => 'thin'

Comment: You might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278817/is-sinatra-multi-threaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [async-sinatra](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra).

Answer (score 1):

Thin is multithreaded but you need to tell it how many servers to start: `thin start --servers 3`. Otherwise it won't have enough workers to serve your requests. See [Usage](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/) in the docs.

Comment: This is a nice workaround but it's not a complete solution. The `--servers n` argument starts `n` daemons listening on `n` _different_ ports. If I understood OP correctly the goal is to make a daemon listening on a _single_ port asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant Jan. Sinatra-synchrony does a pretty good job but I have to stay with Ruby 1.8.7 for some reasons...

Comment: @user858931, could you update the question to make it clear?