# Sinatra with thin, multi thread do not work

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sinatra, thin

I have done a simple test on my Sinatra app, when I call the long handler, the dummy request is blocked.

```
 get '/test/long' do
    sleep 10
    "finished"
 end 

 get '/test/dummy' do
    "dummy"

 end
```

I started my server using this command:

```
bundle exec rackup -s thin
```

According to [Is Sinatra multi threaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278817/is-sinatra-multi-threaded), Thin should be a multi thread web server. So what is my problem here?

```
my Gemfile:
source :rubyforge
gem 'sinatra',           '1.2.6', :require => 'sinatra/base'

gem 'geokit',        '1.6.0', :require => 'geokit'
gem 'json',              '1.5.3'
gem 'dm-core',           '1.2.0'
gem 'dm-timestamps',     '1.2.0'
gem 'dm-migrations',     '1.2.0'
gem 'dm-mysql-adapter',  '1.2.0'
gem 'rack-cache',        '1.0.1', :require => 'rack/cache'
gem 'rake',              '10.0.0',  :require => nil
gem 'hashie',            '1.0.0'
gem 'thin'
gem 'shotgun'
gem 'rack-mobile-detect', '0.3.0', :require => 'rack/mobile-detect'
gem 'aws-ses',                     :require => 'aws/ses'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thin can be multi-threaded, but only if you configure it to be so, by default it is single-threaded (evented). From the [answer to the question you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6282999/214790):

> since Sinatra 1.3.0, Thin will be started in threaded mode, if it is started by Sinatra (i.e. with `ruby app.rb`, but not with the `thin` command, nor with `rackup`).

There doesn’t appear to be a way to get `rackup` to pass the threaded option through to Thin, so you will need to use either `thin start --threaded` or `ruby my_app.rb` to get threading on Thin.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this in Rack::Handler with out Sinatra. The 'run' method takes a block parameter, which gives you access to Thin::Server object and you can set all parameters through it.

```
  require 'thin'
  require 'rack'

  class App
            def initialize()
               puts 'init'
    end

    def call(env)
            puts 'got it'
            sleep(60)
            [ 200, { "Content-Type" => "text/plain" }, ["hello"] ]
    end

  end

  Rack::Handler::Thin.run(App.new, options = {:Host => '0.0.0.0', :Port => 8083}) do |server|
       puts server.class
       server.threaded = true
  end
```