# twilio, sinatra ruby force hangup and then callback

Tags: ruby, sinatra, twilio

I want to call my Twilio number which hangs up immediately and then calls me back. This is similar (but not identical) to a previous question of mine.

The problem lies with forcing Twilio to hang up.

The ruby code is:

```
    get '/callback' do
    to = params['From']
    from = 'my Twilio number'
    "<Response><Hangup/></Response>"
    sleep 5
    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => from, # From your Twilio number
    :to => to, # To any number
    # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
    :url => 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85088004/twilio/twilio.xml'
    ) 
end
```

This produces a message: "We are sorry but a system error has occurred". The problem lies with the hangup instruction. I have tried as above and also

```
<Response><Hangup/></Response> #without enclosing double or single quotes
```

and

```
Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
r.Hangup
end.text
```

Neither produces the desired result of hangup.

What's wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely go with @Kevin's advice and get in touch with Twilio support. But one comment I would like to add. At the end of your `/callback` action, the last value is the `@call` variable you are assigning when you create a call, Ruby will be trying to return this value as the result of the HTTP request.

Ruby returns the last value evaluated at the end of a method. In this case, that value is what Sinatra responds to the HTTP Get request with by default.

Judging by the literal string you have `<Response><Hangup/></Response>`, I'm guessing you are not using a view, and expect that to be the result of the get request. You should place that at the very end of your method as below. I've also added a `content_type` which just sets the response header to say the response is XML.

```
get '/callback' do
    to = params['From']
    from = 'my Twilio number'
    # set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
    @call = @client.account.calls.create(
      :from => from, # From your Twilio number
      :to => to, # To any number
      # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
      :url => 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85088004/twilio/twilio.xml') 
    #ruby returns the last value in a method:
    content_type 'text/xml'
    "<Response><Hangup/></Response>"
end
```

Make sure that you have your Twilio Voice Callback set to a Get request as well (the default is post).

I've also removed the `sleep 5` that you had in there. I can see where you are going with it. Respond with the `hangup` TwiML, wait a few seconds, then make a new call. Sadly, Sinatra doesn't quite work that way. It will not respond to the HTTP request until the end of the method. So you're just going to have it sit and wait for 5 seconds with no reason.

This does pose a bit of an issue, as you tell Twilio to make an outbound call to the number that you are about to hangup on, so you basically have a race condition. Does the call disconnect first, or does the outbound start ringing to a busy number.

There are a number of ways of doing this, but I'd suggest a thread. It's a little tricky, but this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278817/is-sinatra-multi-threaded) goes into some detail.

Comment: thanks very much, I appreciate your thoughtful answer. I will give it a shot and let you know. I had figured out the need to set my Twilio url to "get", that's potentially a real "gotcha" but thanks for noting it. Kevin, thanks too!

Comment: thank you xmjw, it works great. I cannot get my head round the fact that the hangup xml appears after it is supposed to call me back rather than before! Why is this?

Comment: It's because of the lack of concurrency. You have a single thread that receives the HTTP GET request, makes another HTTP call to Twilio's REST API, then writes some TwiML back into the response stream to the original GET request. So it doesn't write the response data until after it has had a reply from Twilio's REST API saying the outbound call has been initiated. Everything is happening sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Twilio Debugger at twilio.com/user/account/debugger. This will give more information about the failure.

Comment: thanks, I did but I cannot relate the information to a solution. I will post the debug here. Is the code correct, in your view?

Comment: It's hard to say. Does the debugger report it can't reach your server? Does it report that the TwiML was invalid?

Comment: thanks, it's either a "document parse failure" or "http retrieval error". I am sure that the problem is forcing the hangup but I am not sure what the correct code to achieve that is.

Comment: Can you please email help at twilio dot com or provide a public URL where we can hit the hangup endpoint? It's hard to debug further without knowing more about the situation. Other useful information would include the complete HTTP response, including headers.